React Native ScrollView Not Scrolling Due to contentContainerStyle Height
I am having issues with my code because when the content exceed the height content, I can't scroll
My actual code looks like this:
<SafeAreaView className="bg-primary h-full">
   <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ height: "100%" }}>
       <Text> TEST </Text>
       <Text> TEST </Text>
       <Text> TEST </Text>
       <Text> TEST </Text>
       ...
   </ScrollView>
<SafeAreaView />

I have tried changing contentContainerStyle={{ height: "80%" }}, but it still doesn't work

Try using contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}

I had similar problem, just use  and then use  for content, Ignore the contentContainerStyle. It might not be the correct way as such but worked for me
